# Deploy MVC 3 app and generate Database (IIS 7, SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an MVC app to a server which is running IIS 7 and has SQL Server 2008 R2. I have set up web config transformations so that I can dev on my local machine with Sql Server CE and added a connection string in the Release config so that it points to a new (empty) database I created on the server. The application is written code first.

How do I generate the required tables for the application on the server? I have tried to deploy my app through VS publish using File System as the publish method but this does not do anything on the database side. Do I need to use Web Deploy as the publish method (would this make a difference)? A database initalise strategy such as CreateDatabaseIfNotExists?

Completely at a loss here so any tips or links to walkthroughs would be appreciated.

Comment: We are totally at a loss, either, because primarily you should ask your hoster for how he plans this to happen. vs has a wizard to deploy databases, but it must be activated also on teh server side. You provide a very leightweith (not to say useless) level of detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott Gu explains it in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx), in addition to web config transformations you could also perform database deployments during the publishing process:

> VS 2010 allows you to optionally deploy a database, along with your
>   web application files, when are using the “Web Deploy” option as your
>   deployment mechanism. Databases deployed this way can include both
>   schema and data, and can optionally also include change scripts to
>   update existing databases.
>
> ASP.NET Web Projects in VS 2010 have a special page within their the
>   “project properties” settings to configure database deployments:

Comment: Thanks. Yeah Web Deploy is the way to go, generates the database as requested.